# HTTP Post to Php isn't working

Tags: android, http, post, http-post, httpclient

The code isn't working. Please help. The item gets added to the database except for the quantity. It's always zero. Why is that?

```
String value;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.creamy);

    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CreamyEdit);
    value = et.getText().toString();

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCreamy);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(Creamy.this, "Item Submitted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                    "http://10.0.2.2:8080/http/test.php");

            List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


       pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("item", "Creamy Delight"));   //reflected in db
       pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("quantity", value));          //not reflected in db


        try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });
```

Help please!

Comment: I use Gingerbread (2.3.3)

Comment: Show us the server-side code handling the request.

Comment: @TomeTasche <?php

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","");
if( !$connection ) {
 die("database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

$select_db = mysql_select_db('db_asiabrewerydemo', $connection);
if( !$select_db ) {
 die("database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
}


$item = $_REQUEST['item'];
$quantity = $_REQUEST['quantity'];




 $strSql = "INSERT INTO items (item_name, quantity)
      VALUES('$item', '$quantity') ";
  
 $query = mysql_query($strSql) or die(mysql_error());
 
 if($query){
   echo "success";
 }else {
   echo "failed";
} 
?>

Comment: Paul, please add the code to your original question. I can't properly read it in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the line `value = et.getText().toString();` into the `onClick` method. If you call `et.getText` in onCreate it always returns an empty string, because that's all that's inside the EditText at the time of onCreate.